# Divide and conquer sum algorithm

Tags: c++, sorting, array-algorithms

i was looking for some D&C algorithms and came out founding this one

```
int sumArray(int anArray[], int size)
{
    //base case
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (size == 1)
    {
        return anArray[0];
    }

    //divide and conquer
    int mid = size / 2;
    int rsize = size - mid;
    int lsum = sumArray(anArray, mid);
    int rsum = sumArray(anArray + mid, rsize);
    return lsum + rsum;
}
```

but everytime i run the code without the base case it returns a segment fault error.
im trying to figure out why this base case is so important that even running with n>1 it stills returning that error, someone would lend a hand here?

Comment: If you never return as a base case, you obviously recurse forever... which will fill up the stack with stack frames and thus segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function `sumArray` calls itself recursively,

```
    int lsum = sumArray(anArray, mid);
    int rsum = sumArray(anArray + mid, rsize);
```

the base case is needed regardless of the size of the array. Otherwise Fnction can never exit the loop of calling itself!
And remember that base on the fact that one of `mid` and `rsize` could be odd or even both base cases for `size == 0` and `size == 1`:

```
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (size == 1)
    {
        return anArray[0];
    }
```

are needed

Comment: ooh yeah of course, i forgot about recursion part, thank you.

Comment: @theguissan you'r welcome. and thank you for asking the question. Also do not pay too much attention to down votes